# Running Viber as another user while using "mine" X Server's microphine and speakers

Tags: fedora, security, gnome, selinux, jails

I run *Fedora* with *GNOME* and recently installed [*Viber* for linux](http://www.viber.com/products/linux/). It's very good and all is working just fine.

As *Viber* is not *open-source* software, I decided to run it as another user **to make sure that it doesn't have access to my files without my concent**, by creating a *user:group* `viber:viber`. If I try to open from inside *Viber* files that belong to me or any other user, it can't read them. **Goal achieved but partly.** Now, I stumbled against another problem, which is *Viber* works only with **messages** and when I try to make a call, it says, that it **can't find neither microphone nor speakers?** It feels that I know why (I run X Server (GNOME) as *myself* and *Viber* as *viber:viber (user:group)* ).

**How to make *Viber* run as `viber:viber` and at the same time, to let it use microphone and speakers, while running GNOME session as `myusername:myusername`?**

SELinux solutions are also welcome but with concrete examples! *chroot* is not the solution, as it will lead, as I understand, to the same problem as described above.

#### EDIT 1:

The *exec* for running it is: `su - viber -c /opt/viber/Viber`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wasn't aware of Pulseaudio running on Fedora as audio server.

After researching, I have finally found a way to share audio (microphone and speakers) among other users, while running Pulseaudio as normal user (myself) and not in *System Mode*.

In order to do that you will only need to copy initial configuration file to your home directory:

```
cp /etc/pulse/default.pa  ~/.pulse/default.pa
```

Afterwards, add the following configuration option to it (`~/.pulse/default.pa`):

`load-module module-native-protocol-tcp auth-ip-acl=127.0.0.1`

Now, under those *users/user*, that you want to share the audio with, in their home directories (NOT YOURS) create Pulseaudio custom user-config file `~/.pulse/client.conf` and add the following option:

```
default-server = 127.0.0.1
```

Don't forget to restart your audio server or your computer/server to apply new settings.

Eventually, I can run *Viber* as another user `viber:viber` and have access to microphone and speakers, while running GNOME session as `myusername:myusername`.

---

Successfully tested on *Fedora 20*.

Answer (score 4):

You need to run [pulseaudio in system mode](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/SystemWide/), and let all users access it, unfortunately, this is [strongly discouraged by the upstream Pulseaudio developers](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/WhatIsWrongWithSystemWide/).

Here's a systemd service script that should improve on the above:

```
# /etc/systemd/system/pulseaudio.service:
[Unit]
Description=PulseAudio Daemon
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
[Service]
Type=simple
PrivateTmp=true
ExecStart=/usr/bin/pulseaudio --system --disallow-exit
```

If you want to run with SELinux enabled, here is a [post describing the SELinux rules needed](https://elehack.net/writings/computing/audio-server).

Comment: Robbat, thanks for your helpful hint about *Pulseaudio*. Though Fedora doesn't have such settings! Fedora's configs are located in `/etc/pulse/`. I have managed to solve my problem without running it in *System Mode*. Take a look at my answer! +1 for giving a push to the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

Careful, `/opt/viber/Viber` has SUID and GUID bits set. It will probably run as root nevertheless (I did not test it, though).

Comment: Interesting point, but it's only valid, if files were owned by `root`. I don't leave Viber files owned by root and assigned separate *user/group* for it. It can't run as root if the files owned by another user, right?

Comment: I think in your case, you are fine. 

Standard installation procedure of todays viber.deb file (2014-04-23) is to copy the files to /usr/share/viber (which usually requires root privileges) and then do a "chmod a+s" on "Viber" and "Viber.sh".

Maybe this should be mentioned, to not lead unexperienced users to false sense of security.

Comment: I didn't install `.deb` package as I have `.rpm`. I just unpacked it. Besides never ran *Viber.sh*. I think it din't break the jail I made for it.